# SceneKit OverlaySKScene on MacOS not visible

Tags: ios, swift, macos, sprite-kit, scenekit

I would like to create a MacOS application using Swift and SceneKit from scratch [using the Cocoa application template].
Somehow my overlay SpriteKit scene isn't visible while the same steps do work on iOS.

Steps taken:

- new project > cocoa application
- add sceneview to main.storyboard
- add outlet from sceneview to viewcontroller

Code added to viewDidLoad:

```
// Create scenekit-scene
// ---------------------
let scene = SCNScene()

let nodeCamera = SCNNode()
nodeCamera.camera = SCNCamera()
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeCamera)

let box = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
box.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = NSColor.blue
let nodeBox = SCNNode(geometry: box)
nodeBox.position = SCNVector3(0,0, -2)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeBox)

// Add to view
sceneView.scene = scene


// Create spritekit-scene
// ----------------------
let spriteScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: sceneView.frame.width, height: sceneView.frame.height))

let nodelabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Menlo")
nodelabel.text = "SpriteKit"
nodelabel.fontColor = NSColor.black
nodelabel.position = CGPoint(x: spriteScene.size.width/2, y: spriteScene.size.height/2)
spriteScene.addChild(nodelabel)

// Add to scenekit
sceneView.overlaySKScene = spriteScene
```

In the iOS-simulator I see a blue cube with black "SpriteKit" in the middle. On MacOS I only see the blue cube.

[BTW: What is kind of strange: when I use the MacOS game template [scenekit] the overlaySKScene functions normal and is visible.]

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

While comparing the storyboards scene view properties between the cocoa-template and the game-template I noticed the view controller's view in the cocoa-template had a **check-mark** in **view effects inspector>core animation layer**.

When unchecked the OverlaySKScene became visible.